ASP.NET Core returns statuscode 0 when long polling timeouts before .NET 8. In .NET 8, it returns statuscode 499
We have an ASP.NET Core application that the client normally uses long polling to get results:

before .NET 8, when long polling times out, the client throws a timeout exception which is expected. On the server side, there is no exception thrown and the server logs it as successful operation with return status code 0

In .NET 8, when long polling timeouts, the client throws a timeout exception, while on the server side, it logs this as an exception and returns status code 499.

The problem is now server side has much more exceptions that before and slowed down client side. The server side has more exceptions, bigger connections queues etc. The performance is worse than before overall.


Has anybody encountered a similar issue? How can we avoid this?
I tried a few options to disable this exception on the server side, but failed. Looks likes the server side throws an OperationCanceledException when client times out. The exception can't be skipped.
We have both a C++ and a C# client and they encountered similar issues. The C++ client uses boost IO, the C# client uses HttpClient.
This issue only happened after we upgraded to .NET 8
Thanks in advance.

According to your description, there shall be some changes for handling long-polling requests in .Net 8 if you didn't change anything in your codes. If so, maybe we could only try to handle the OperationCanceledException to avoid making server side has much more exceptions than before and slowed down client side.

Weird, somehow similar but not: I have just upgraded my ASP .NET Web API from .NET 6 to .NET 8 and I started to see some 499 errors reported to Application Insights. These are legit API calls that take only a few hundred ms and they are logged as 200 in the IIS HTTP logs.
